# Any way to get the value checkbox

Tags: jquery

Been working with checkboxes and I was curious if there is any way to get the value of something that is "connected" to the checkbox? Whenever I `console.log('input:checked').val()` I get the value of `on`, which is fine but I wanted to save a bit of time. Thanks.

Comment: Please look at this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be handy to lift your quality up

Comment: What do you mean by "connected"? Do you mean the text next to the checkbox? It would be better if you put the information you want in the `<input>` element.

Comment: Do you want to get time when input checkd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val()` returns the value of checkbox if set else returns ***on***.
if you want to check that the checkbox is checked:

```
$(selector).is(':checked')
```

check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sdF2h/120/